# How to refresh web page after closing Model dialog box in rails 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, popup, refresh

I am developing project on rails and I need to refresh the whole web page when I close a Model dialog box. How can I do this on rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with javascript, add hook on modal box closing with something like

```
location.reload(true)
```

This will refresh whole page, if you need to refresh just a partial, you should use AJAX GET action.